# Fedora doesn't see devices attached via Ethernet switch

Tags: ssh, fedora, ethernet, switch, nmap

I'm trying to figure out how networking is build and have made a mini-network for practicing. The structure is following:

[image: Structure]

**What I want to do:**

- Enable Ethernet connection between from main machine to Raspberry Pi for further ssh use
- bridge the outer Wi-Fi connection to switch and further use of it with PRi (for updates and etc.)

**What I'm doing**

After installing Fedora server to main machine, I'm enabling ssh:

```
sudo dnf install openssh-server
sudo systemctl enable sshd.service
sudo systemctl start sshd.service
reboot
```

After that I'm able to connect to it from local network with no problem. Next, I flash the latest [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latest) image to SD cards of several Raspberry Pi computers and [enabling ssh](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) on each of them.

Then I connect switch  (tried these 2 switches: [LinkSys SD205](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbus/SD205_SD208_SD216/quick_start/guide/SD205_208_216_QuickStartv1.pdf) and [LinkSys BEFSR41](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/BEFSR41_V43_UG_A-WEB.pdf)) to main server and Raspberries with Ethernet cables. Running `ifconfig` in terminal says, that computer sees the outer connection (WiFi), but doesn't see the Ethernet connection, since it doesn't assigns the IP addresses to Ethernet port.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether __:__:__:__:__:__  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 589  bytes 42571 (41.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59  bytes 9982 (9.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 21  memory 0xf7ae0000-f7b00000  

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast aaa.bbb.ccc.255
        inet6 ____::____:____:___:____  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether __:__:__:__:__:__  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2044  bytes 1590715 (1.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2067  bytes 1557997 (1.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Search shows that I need to provide static IP for Ethernet on main machine to make it work (assume, I want static IP 192.168.10.1):

`sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

Here edit or add following lines:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR=192.168.10.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
```

After that:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

After that it sees the connection and assigns the IP address:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

but, I can't see any device attached to switch, when I'm trying to scan it:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.10.1/24
```

It results in:

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-04-11 17:20 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.1
Host is up (0.00049s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 2.51 seconds
```

Also, this modification cuts off my wireless connection after reboot.
What is wrong at this point and how to fix it?

P.S. Also tried option:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.1
sudo ifconfig eth0 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Also didn't work

**UPDATE 1** Fix of network discovery

For some reason assigning of IP via editing `/boot/cmdline.txt` of Raspberry Pi didn't work. Assigning of IP worked when I re-flashed fresh Raspbian and edited `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` by adding several lines:

```
interface eth0
    static ip_address=192.168.10.xx/24
    static ip_routers=192.168.10.1
    static ip_domain_name_servers=192.168.10.1
```

Where `ip_routers` and `ip_domain_name_servers` is IP address assigned Ethernet card of main server.

Comment: Can you check the IP address of each unit? If they're not on the same IP range, they're note likely to be able to see one another. The switch won't automatically make it a network, the devices all need to be assigned IP addresses within the same range.

Comment: They've been manually assigned before first boot. Since they are connected via Ethernet, you can add ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to cmdline.txt file in boot partition. I assigned them as 192.168.10.3, 192.168.10.16, 192.168.10.27. This is why I'm using 192.168.10.1 as IP for main machine.

Comment: I've frequently found in frustrating situations like this, you may need to attach a display to one of the RPis.  it's possible, for example, that they're not actually bringing their interface up.  Or it's possible they're trying to do DHCP still.  You might run `tcpdump -i eth0 -n` and watch what it displays when you turn on a RPi to see if they're sending any traffic under a different address.

Comment: @WesHardaker OK, I'll check it tomorrow (I already out of office).
P.S. Isn't blinking LEDs nearby Ethernet port a confirmation of started data exchange?

Comment: You'd hope so, but I wouldn't trust them :-)

Comment: Yes, It did see the IP, but didn't work. What is more frustrating: I re-flashed fresh images of Raspbian, but this time I assigned the IP via editing /etc/dhcpcd.conf before first run. And it worked instantly. I don't understand what happened.

Comment: Problem with static IP on Fedora machine is still active